# jquery-1.8.2.js crash with internet explorer browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, cross-browser, compatibility

Hello I'm going crazy behind this compatibility issue with ie.
The problem occurs only with internet explorer (I have version 10), I have no problems with firefox.
I'm trying to open a sliding form (not created by me, specifically: 
[a link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/)
but when I go to run the code (only on internet explorer) I get the following exception.
Do you know tell me what is due?

```
// Use this for any attribute in IE6/7    
// This fixes almost every IE6/7 issue
nodeHook = jQuery.valHooks.button = {
get: function( elem, name ) {
var ret;
ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
return ret && ( fixSpecified[ name ] ? ret.value !== "" : ret.specified ) ?
ret.value :undefined;
},
set: function( elem, value, name ) {
// Set the existing or create a new attribute node
var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
if ( !ret ) {
ret = document.createAttribute( name );
elem.setAttributeNode( ret );
}
return ( ret.value = value + "" ); --> exception in jquery-1.8.2.js cannot find a member
}
};
```

I was forgetting, I'm using vc2012 with a template mvc4.

Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue normally arises when trying to run your app in IE 10 using different browser modes.

To fix that press `F12` and check for the Browser mode and Document Mode. Probably one of them is `IE 8` or below. Change the "Browser Mode" to "**IE10**" and "Document Mode" to "**Standards**".