# JQuery is broken in the default ASP.MVC 4 internet application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been getting some odd behavior on my MVC 4 application where it's erroring on some sections of JQuery.  Just merely loading a single page with the JQuery bundle was broken.

So I went and created a brand new MVC 4 application and tried to run it.  Sure enough:

Exception was thrown at line 5302, column 6 in localhost:49856/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js

This is the DEFAULT MVC 4 app.  Literally I created it, then tried to browse it in IE 11.  I have even tried updating JQuery and all other Nuget packages on the app, still the same error.

Comment: Do you have same error in other browsers, or only in IE 11?

Comment: Check this thread, it seems that you have same problem (mvc 4 + jquery 1.8.2): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397264/jquery-1-8-2-js-crash-with-internet-explorer-browser